# How to perform time-consuming task inside callback function in ROS

Tags: c++, callback, ros

This question is more likely a coding hack and may not depend on [ROS](http://www.ros.org/). I am receiving data from a subscriber inside a callback function. I am trying to perform time-consuming task inside this function. Please see the code snippet-

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

class TimeConsumingTask {
private:
  bool still_processing;
  void callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr &msg);

public:
  TimeConsumingTask();
};

void TimeConsumingTask::callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr &msg) {
  ROS_INFO("callback received");
  if (still_processing)
    return;

  still_processing = true;
  // perform time consuming task
  ros::Duration(5).sleep();
  still_processing = false;
}
}

TimeConsumingTask::TimeConsumingTask() {
  still_processing = false;
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub =
      n.subscribe("hello_word", 10, &TimeConsumingTask::callback, this);
  ros::spin();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");
  TimeConsumingTask task;
  return 0;
}
```

I planned to use a flag to skip the next call if the previous task isn't finished. However, it didn't work!

Although it is suggested not to do any time-consuming task inside callback function. I have no issues, even if I skip few callbacks. **I want to know if there exists a hack to perform time-consuming task inside callback function in ROS.**

PS: I am using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit OS. Please use `rostopic pub -r 10 hello_word std_msgs/String hello` to publish sample message.

Comment: Did you already tought about using [actions](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) to solve this problem?

Comment: No. I haven't! Can you please describe it?

Comment: Check out the link I've added to my first comment. There is already a great description.

Comment: I haven't tested myself but u can use boost threads to do what u intend so every new call will be detached to a thread

Comment: @MohammadAli: Thank you very much for the suggestion. Since we are performing time-consuming task inside each thread, the number of threads can grow dramatically. I guess!